# CSS transition interferes with animation

Tags: html, css

I have this css :

```
.yellowText {
    color: #FFFF00;
    -ms-transform: rotate(-20deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(-20deg);
}

.pulse {
    -webkit-animation: text-anim;
    animation: text-anim 1s;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes text-anim {
    0% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
    50% { -webkit-transform: scale(1.1); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
}

@keyframes text-anim {
    0% { transform: scale(1); }
    50% { transform: scale(1.1); }
    100% { transform: scale(1); }
}
```

Then, I apply it to a text :

```
<p class="yellowText pulse">Some text here</p>
```

But now, the text is well-animated, without being rotated by -20°... Any idea of what could be wrong ? I believe this is a problem with the `transform` property not working with the `animation` one. Also, what I tried was putting the `transform` inside the `@keyframes text-anim`, but what this does is just periodically rotating the text, having it perfectly right the rest of the time...

Thanks in advance for your help !

*PS : forgive my bad English, I'm French :P*

Comment: add to your keyframes transform the rotation you need. https://jsfiddle.net/keypaul/cqurxLeq/1/

Comment: Sorry but what about my comment...

Comment: Well obviously, your jsfiddle doesn't work since there's a remaining `100% { transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);}`... Otherwise, the answer giver by @nicholas-tibbs is the same as your :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `@keyframes` are overriding you original transform property.

```
@-webkit-keyframes text-anim {
    0% { -webkit-transform: scale(1 rotate(-20deg); }
    50% { -webkit-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(-20deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: scale(1) rotate(-20deg); }
}

@keyframes text-anim {
    0% { transform: scale(1) rotate(-20deg); }
    50% { transform: scale(1.1) rotate(-20deg); }
    100% { transform: scale(1) rotate(-20deg); }
}
```